# Error using threads in python socket for remote control

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to build a small remote control software using python socket that controls the mouse and keyboard (I'm also trying to send screenshots but in the meantime I'm trying to get the mouse and keyboard to work) I've used threading for each function, but there's no output I've tried several levels but no case worked properly. Would appreciate help

server:

```
import io
import socket
import threading
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
import pyautogui
import keyboard as kb
import _json
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False


def mouse(sock, address):
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        mouse_data = f"{x},{y}".encode()
        data = ("mouse", mouse_data)
        sock.send(data)

def keyboard(sock, address):
    while True:
        local_keyboard_data = kb.read_event()
        data = ("keyboard", local_keyboard_data)
        sock.sendall(str(data).encode('utf-8'))

'''''''''
def img():
    while True:
        try:
            img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10, 10, 500, 500))
            photo_to_send = img.tobytes()

            size = len(photo_to_send)

            server_socket.send(bytes(str(size), 'utf-8'))
            server_socket.send(photo_to_send)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error sending image data:", e)
            break
'''''
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8090
sock.bind((ip, port))
sock.listen(1)
print("Server is listening")


while True:
    server_socket, address = sock.accept()
    mouse_thread = threading.Thread(target=mouse, args=(server_socket, address))
    keyboard_thread = threading.Thread(target=keyboard, args=(server_socket, address))
    # img_thread = threading.Thread(target=img, args=(server_socket, address))

    mouse_thread.start()
    keyboard_thread.start()
    # img_thread.start()

    # mouse_thread.join()
    # keyboard_thread.join()
    # img_thread.join()
```

client:

```
import io
import socket
import threading
import time
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

def mouse(sock):
    while True:
        mouse_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if mouse_data[0] == "mouse":
            x, y = map(int, mouse_data.decode().split(','))
            pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)


def keyboard(sock):
    while True:
        keyboard_data = sock.recv(1024)
        decoded_data = keyboard_data.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
        if keyboard_data[0] == "keyboard":
            print(f"Remote key press: {decoded_data}")
            pyautogui.press(decoded_data)


'''''''''''
def img():
    while True:
        try:
            size = int(sock.recv(10).decode('utf-8'))
            the_photo = sock.recv(size)
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(the_photo))
            image.show()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error receiving and displaying image data:", e)
            break
'''''''''

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8090))
sock.send("connected client".encode())

while True:
    mouse_thread = threading.Thread(target=mouse, args=(sock,))
    keyboard_thread = threading.Thread(target=keyboard, args=(sock,))
    # img_thread = threading.Thread(target=img)

    mouse_thread.start()
    keyboard_thread.start()
    # img_thread.start()

    # mouse_thread.join()
    # keyboard_thread.join()
    # img_thread.join()
```

I tried sending them in array and jason and nothing worked
I would appreciate it if you could help me

Comment: 1. You should use a threading.Lock when attempting to send data from 2 or more threads at the same time, after all there's no telling that socket.send or any other socket method are thread-safe. 2. Note that socket.send [may not send](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) the entire message right away. It's up to you to check that out, or as you did it already, use socket.sendall. 3. Most socket methods raise exceptions, I recommend using try-catch on them.